# SVN start transaction

Tags: svn, transactions, rollback

Is there a way that I would start transaction and commit like in a databases?
I don't mean commit files but modifications on server directly. I need it for scripting purposes.

For example:

```
svn start-transaction
svn mv server1/some_dir server1/some_dir2
svn cp server1/some_dir2 server1/some_dir3
svn cp server1/some_dir2 server1/some_dir4

and so on...

svn commit-transaction
some error handle
```

My point is if any of these commands fails, there will not be a change on server. Basically, database rollback if any of these commands fail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using svn commit in a working copy? That's the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some subversion commands - like `cp` - can be done completely server-side, but it will be an immediate commit (a revision in and of itself).  Subversion only guarantees atomicity at the commit level.  If you need to do more than one thing in a single atomic operation, then you need to run those commands on your working copy and then do a single commit back to the repository.